# C# ClickOnce options

Tags: c#, ftp, clickonce, windows

This is about C# ClickOnce options for a Windows desktop application.

Can I make my application takes file from an FTP server and install the application? Then every time it looks for an update it would check my FTP server.

Or works similar like this. In other words, I installed the application and could search for an update on the FTP server and once found, download and install it.

Comment: Have you done [any research](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+clickonce+ftp)?

Comment: Done, tried, but didnt worked, so asking if this is possible

Comment: @Mac444s Show your effort. Explain what "didnt worked".

Comment: I published new version of app in ftp but program didnt find when searching for update. Maybe im doing some huge mistake somewhere couse im newbie :S

Comment: Why do you manually want to check for updates when ClickOnce is designed for semi-automating the process (the user still have to chose to update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an FTP site to publish the ClickOnce files to, but all the files have to be signed in the manifest before publishing. So I don't think you would be able have a ClickOnce check for external files.

Comment: oh, then I will research more, maybe find some way.

Comment: Yes, but does ClickOnce updating actually work from an FTP server (if that is question - is not really clear)? Or does it only over HTTP and with UNC paths (e.g. a file server)

Comment: What do you mean by "external files"? ClickOnce updating *does* work over the Internet (using HTTP).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I assumed he meant that he was wanting to publish his ClickOnce, then have it search an FTP for updates.  I don't think ClickOnce supports FTP for client updates